# How to pan a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How to pan a leaflet map  to the point when a marker is dragged?

```
startMarker.on('dragged', function(event) {});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
startMarker.on('dragend', function(event) {
 map.setView(new L.LatLng( event.target.getLatLng().lat,event.target.getLatLng().lng),zoom);
});
```

Comment: I suggest `map.panTo(this.getLatLng());` instead of `map.setView(...)`.